# How can I add Wolfram Alpha to search bar in Chrome?

Tags: browser, searchbar

I want to send queries to Wolfram Alpha real fast. I've been using `wiki query` from search bar for ages, how can I search on WA?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ultimately I found the solution myself, but it took me some time and I had to devise the solution myself, since all Google searches returned the extension which I wanted to avoid. Here it is.

1. Right click the address bar and click `Edit search engines...`
   (or open `Settings -> Search -> Manage search engines...`)
2. Usually, you can find all recognized search engines you used already listed there, but if not, add this: *(*use any keyword of your choice)*
   [image]

   The query url: `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%s`

Now it is possible to use `wa query` from search bar to search on Wolfram Alpha. Note, this method allows you to use any search engine.

Comment: I just went to add this to my Chrome search engines and found it was already there! Not sure if it gets added by default, or perhaps when you do a search on the WA website, but the `wa` keyword seems to already be in place. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

This is really handy! I wonder if adding it in Chrome as a search engine is better than using the Wolfram Alpha chrome extension though. That is much easier to search using just combination of "=" followed by space and you can directly type in your search query to the Math engine :)

[Wolfram|Alpha (Official)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wolframalpha-official/icncamkooinmbehmkeilcccmoljfkdhp)
Instantly query Wolfram|Alpha from any page or tab.

There is more to it, you can type formula and equations directly in your navigation bar using this on any page or tab. Pretty neat!

[image]

[Source]: From [Wolfram Alpha Official Chrome Extension page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wolframalpha-official/icncamkooinmbehmkeilcccmoljfkdhp)

===FEATURES===

✓ Wolfram|Alpha Button – Access the Wolfram|Alpha query box with just one click. You can also right-click the Wolfram|Alpha icon to change extension options.

✓ Omnibox Shortcut – Transform Chrome's omnibox into a Wolfram|Alpha query field by typing an = sign followed by a space.

✓ Context Menu Shortcut – Highlight text to create queries through a context menu (right-click) entry.

**Shouting out to StackOverflow community**:
I am still learning and appreciating the power of this engine. If you guys have some resources or content apart from Wolfram's official site, please do share!
This will really help me as a beginner in the field and I can use to improve.

What better way to search than the famous **Euler's Identity**. In Chrome Nav bar

```
"=" ==> (space) ==> e^(i*pie) ==> (enter)
```

Or something like:

```
"=" ==> (space) ==> sqrt(1779)*cube(pi) ==> (enter)
```

And see the result instantly in Wolfram. Awesome isn't it?

Comment: This looked promising, but unfortunately, the extension doesn't execute even simple calculations like the chrome omnibox itself does. It is not different or faster than setting a custom keyword `=` like in the other answer. The only added value is that one can send a selected text via right-click to a wolfram-alpha page directly.